# ind-completion and ordinals

Tags: category-theory, ordinals

Given a category $C$, we have its ind-completion $Ind(C)$ whose objects are filtered diagrams in $C$.

Assuming the axiom of choice, is any object in $Ind(C)$ isomorphic, in $Ind(C)$, to an ordinal indexed filter?

Comment: More concretely, does every directed poset admit a cofinal map from an ordinal?

Comment: That might have been a better question.

Comment: I don't understand the question, but as phrased by @Zhen Lin, the answer is trivially negative. Consider the finite subsets of $\omega_1$ (or any uncountable set of uncountable cofinality) ordered by inclusion. The "height" is $\omega$, but there is no cofinal set of countable size.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: Can you explain, in a sentence, what's $\operatorname{Ind}(\mathcal C)$?

Comment: Thanks.  I think that answers my question.  Ind(C) is the free cocompletion of C under filtered colimits.  So it's basically C plus all colimits of filtered diagrams in C.

Comment: $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ is basically the category of "formal direct limits" of directed systems in $\mathcal{C}$. Alex's question and my question are closely related, but I am not completely sure they are equivalent. The fact of the matter is, if you have direct limits for all ordinal-indexed directed  systems, then you have direct limits for all directed systems – but you have to build them up iteratively!

Comment: I'm also not 100% sure that this question should be tagged under [axiom-of-choice]. Because the question doesn't seem to ask about the role of the axiom in this proof, or what happens when the axiom of choice fails. (And sure enough, it is possible to construct models of set theory where the axiom of choice fails, and there are partial orders closed under any ordinal limits, but not generally complete.

Answer (score 1):

No.  For instance, let $C$ be the category of finite sets, and let $X$ be an uncountable set.  The collection of all finite subsets of $X$ (and their inclusion maps) form a filtered diagram in $C$ and hence an object of $Ind(C)$.  However, this object cannot be represented by an ordinal-indexed diagram.  Indeed, suppose $(Y_\beta)_{\beta<\alpha}$ is a diagram in $C$ indexed by an ordinal $\alpha$, with maps $f_{\beta\gamma}:Y_\beta\to Y_\gamma$ when $\beta<\gamma$.  Then the colimit $Y$ of this diagram in $Set$ must be countable: $Y$ is the union of the images of each $Y_\beta$ in $Y$, so it is the union of a chain of finite subsets.  But isomorphic objects of $Ind(C)$ have isomorphic colimits in $Set$ (the colimit is a functor $Ind(C)\to Set$, in fact an equivalence of categories), and the colimit of our diagram of finite subsets of $X$ is just $X$ which is uncountable.  Thus $(Y_\beta)$ cannot be isomorphic to the diagram of finite subsets of $X$.